# How to create a custom share sheet like Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, share

I'm building a social media app in iOS using Swift. I noticed that if I share things using Facebook's "Share app 'droplet'" in the share sheet, it will open a custom Facebook share sheet on top of the original app that share it, instead of opening the Facebook app and then showing share/post screen.

[image: Facebook custom share sheet]

It's not an ordinary share screen. I can select if I want to share to a user, to a group, or to some selected friends using privacy. So it's not static. But I'm guessing it's also not retrieving some data from the internet just to update the list, so this is a cached list.

[image]

How can I create something like this? I tried to search on the internet, but all I get is just how to import files to my app from other app, not to create a custom share sheet. I do also need to import files from other app to my app, but that's for another topic. At least I need the keyword to start research about this, because I don't even know what to search for this.

Comment: For people who vote to close the question because it's too broad, the question looks too broad because I want to know exactly how to narrow it, by asking for the key word / key concept to search here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called Share Extensions, or more generally App Extensions.

[Here's the relevant Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html)

Comment: Looks like what I need to get started. Thanks!